# php odbc result modified after passing as parameter

Tags: php, odbc

`$out = odbc_exec($connection, $query);
 $first = odbc_fetch_array($out);`
 works just fine

`$out = odbc_exec($connection, $query);
 $first = odbc_num_rows($out);`
 works just fine

```
 $out = odbc_exec($connection, $query);
 $first = odbc_fetch_array($out);
 if(odbc_num_rows($out)) {
    //This should execute true, but doesn't
 }
```

To my knowledge, any variable you pass (`$out`) to a function are only read. 
How can calling `fetch_array` cause `num_rows` to error?

**Update**
I've even copied the result straight after the odbc_exec into a 'temp' variable & used that on the fetch_array, yet still it throws. seriously, what the f.

Comment: what is the error you didnt say that

Comment: the error is later when I attempt an if statement on `odbc_num_rows($out)`. Without calling fetch_array prior to this, the if executes correctly, or true. however calling fetch_array before the if causes it to fail (thus an entire section of code isn't executed when it should be)

Comment: I've var_dump'ed the result before & after the fetch_array, however the results are identical

Comment: Yes but do you get a specific error message, and is there any reason to do this after fetchibg. My guess it has to do with the resultset being fetched

Comment: the reason for fetching is I require a value from the result before I process it using num_rows (a 2nd db query using a key from the initial result). you are right in that the result set being fetched causes this issue, but I can't understand why. 

its a basic programming principle that anything you pass to a function is read, not modified. 

still, This doesn't explain how copying the result into a separate variable also causes the same issue.

Comment: reading through http://php.net reveals user's having behaviour issues with the odbc_ functions. Without diving head first into compiler practises, its looking like some caching is involved. as a result it MAY cause my if statement to not read correctly. this is not confirmed

Comment: The thing is each time u fetch it will  move the recordset pointer to the next row. You saving it to a different variable wont change nothing because in php it they will point to the same reference

Comment: I think the work around is to store the numrow prior to fetching

Answer (score 1):

From PHP Manual:

> **Note:** Using odbc_num_rows() to determine the number of rows available
>   after a SELECT will return -1 with many drivers.

`odbc_num_rows` method is typically used to detect the number of rows modified by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` call.

If you want the full query returned plus the length, loop through the results using `odbc_fetch_array` storing them into an array and then determine the number of tuples from the array length.

If you are only wanting to query the number of rows in a given view, then you are better off to write a query that returns a `COUNT` and fetch that as an array.